# OAuth2 lib works very slow in PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I have created a small API via OAuth2. However, I have noticed that all calls to my API are really slow. To slow. When need to just create token, it takes 3-5 seconds. I have tested API on my local on development server with same 
results. Also, it not matter if I'm making calls from  PHP CURL or any REST API tools/plugin. It always works same slow.

Some parts of my API:

```
$this->storage = new OAuth2\Storage\Pdo(connect(), []);

$this->server = new OAuth2\Server($this->storage);

$this->server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\UserCredentials($this->storage));

$this->response = $this->server->handleTokenRequest(OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals());
```

Comment: Well, no one here can benchmark your code for you, especially since there isn't any code to look at. But you need to be a bit more specific. What, exactly, is slow? How did you measure how slow it is? What approaches did you try.

Comment: You'll need to profile your code to find out where the slowness is coming from, there's not much we can do without the source.